# Apostol proof of first fundamental theorem of calculus under weaker hypothesis of continuity at a point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

In order to show that FTC1 holds under the weaker hypothesis of continuity at a single point, Apostol demonstrates that the proof boils down to proving the limit:

$$ \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h} \int_{x}^{x+h}[f(t)-f(x)] \,dt\  = 0 $$

i.e. we need to show that for any given $\epsilon > 0$, a $\delta > 0$ may be generated such that

$$ \left\lvert\ \frac{1}{h} \int_{x}^{x+h}[f(t)-f(x)] \,dt\  \right\rvert < \epsilon \hspace{2em}\mathrm{whenever}\hspace{1em} 0 < |h| < \delta \tag{1}\label{1}$$

We achieve this by feeding $\epsilon$ to the continuity limit and proving that the resulting $\delta$ satisfies \eqref{1}:

$$ |f(t) - f(x)| < \epsilon\hspace{2em}\mathrm{whenever}\hspace{1em} 0 < | t - x | < \delta $$

Considering the case where $ 0 < h < \delta $, then:

$$ 0 < \frac{1}{h} \int_{x}^{x+h}|f(t)-f(x)| \,dt\ < \frac{1}{h} [h\epsilon] = \epsilon\tag{2}\label{2}$$

since the continuity inequality guarantees the integrand is in the range $[0, \epsilon)$ for the domain $(x, x + \delta)$ and this includes the domain $(x, x + h]$, and since

$$ \left\lvert\ \frac{1}{h} \int_{x}^{x+h}[f(t)-f(x)] \,dt\  \right\rvert < \frac{1}{h} \int_{x}^{x+h}|f(t)-f(x)| \,dt\ \tag{3}\label{3}$$

\eqref{1} is satisfied for the positive $h$ case.

Apostol then says "a similar argument" proves that \eqref{1} holds for $-\delta < h < 0$, and thus the proof is complete.

What I am struggling to understand is how the proofs differ for positive and negative $h$. I assume some aspects of \eqref{2} and/or \eqref{3} are impacted by $h$ being negative, but I can't work out where the machinery of the integral sign breaks down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To attempt to answer my own question, the TL;DR is that I believe equations (2) and (3) hold for negative $h$ without alteration and what Apostol is getting at is that the integrand is also in the range $[0,\epsilon)$ for the domain $(x - \delta,  x)$ and thus if $-\delta < h < 0$ the same argument applies regarding the maximum value of that integrand being $h\epsilon$.

The source of the confusion is that for the proof Apostol introduces the property

$$\left| \int_{x}^{x+h}g(t)\ dt \right|\ \leq\ \int_{x}^{x+h}|g(t)|\ dt   $$

without, as far as I can tell, previously mentioning it. Since the LHS is always positive and the RHS is negative for negative $h$, this property can only hold for positive $h$, which would lead one to believe that the equations that are developed from this property are not usable for negative $h$. If, however, we say

$$\left| \frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}g(t)\ dt \right|\ \leq\ \frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}|g(t)|\ dt   $$

this, I believe, does hold true for negative $h$, and it is this latter inequality that we are actually dealing with.

I actually found the proof is a lot easier to picture if you unpack the absolutes so you can visualise the intersection of the domains. Doing this we can say that continuity guarantees that we can generate $\delta$ such that for any given $\epsilon > 0$

$$-\epsilon < f(t) - f(x) < \epsilon\hspace{2em} \textrm{whenever}\hspace{2em} x - \delta < t < x + \delta  $$

so, as long as $-\delta < h < \delta$

$$-\epsilon\ <\ \frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h} (f(t) - f(x))\ dt\ <\ \epsilon $$

since $(x, x+h)$ is a subset of $(x-\delta, x+\delta)$ and any negatives are automatically accounted for. Repacking the inequalities as absolutes then completes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

FTC 1 says that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$, then $F'(x)=f(x)$. In other words, you need to prove that

\begin{equation} \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}=f(x) \end{equation}

and showing that this limit exists and is equal to the desired value is equivalent to the condition that the left and right-hand limits both exist and are equal to $f(x)$.

In terms of why one needs to show that both one-sided limits exist. Take your favorite example of the overall limit failing to exist when either one or both of the one-sided limits either fails to exist or they don't coincide. For instance, look at any function where there is a jump discontinuity - the one-sided limits won't agree there.

Also, you are right that Apostol could have said that ``a very similar" argument shows the case for $h<0$. Indeed, we have that

\begin{equation} \left\vert\frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}(f(t)-f(x))dt \right\vert \leq \frac{1}{|h|}\int_{x-|h|}^{x}|f(t)-f(x)|dt <\epsilon \end{equation}

if $h$ is negative.

Comment: The last paragraph is the key. The only dissimilarity is that we need to replace $h$ by $|h|$ when we expect a positive number, and keep in mind that $x+h < x$.

Comment: What I'm missing is how the middle part of this inequality is different from equations (2) and (3) for negative $h$? $x - |h| = x + h$ for negative $h$, so the integral is just the negative of the one in (2) and using $\frac{1}{|h|}$ reverses this.

Comment: p.s. Apologies, but I have slightly clarified the question to emphasise that it is the difference in the proofs for positive and negative $h$ that I am interested in, rather than why a proof for negative $h$ is required, which impacts your answer a bit.